How to remove the first row of each unique value in a column in R
I have a data frame as such where the dataframe is ordered by id:
id = c("4_01", "4_01", "4_01", "4_02", "4_02", "4_02", "4_02", "4_03", "4_03", "4_03", "4_03", "4_04", "4_04")
date = c("2020-01-01 12:00:00", "2020-01-01 12:02:00", "2020-01-01 12:04:30","2019-12-23 07:30:00", "2019-12-24 15:35:00","2019-12-28 08:00:00","2019-12-28 12:30:00", "2019-08-20 05:30:00", "2019-08-20 15:30:00","2019-09-28 15:30:00","2019-10-01 12:30:00", "2019-11-01 01:00:00", "2019-11-01 01:30:00")
difftime = c(-700440, 120, 150, -794070, 115230, 318570, 16200,-10922430, 43200, 3369630, 248370, 2637000,1800)
df = data.frame(id, date, difftime)

I can't seem to figure out how to remove the first instance / row of each unique id and keep the remaining rows.
My result would be this, where the first row where the first time each unique ID occurs in the dataset was removed:
id = c("4_01", "4_01", "4_02", "4_02", "4_02", "4_03", "4_03", "4_03", "4_04")
date = c("2020-01-01 12:02:00", "2020-01-01 12:04:30", "2019-12-24 15:35:00","2019-12-28 08:00:00","2019-12-28 12:30:00", "2019-08-20 15:30:00","2019-09-28 15:30:00","2019-10-01 12:30:00", "2019-11-01 01:30:00")
difftime = c(120, 150, 115230, 318570, 16200, 43200, 3369630, 248370, 1800)
df = data.frame(id, date, difftime)

In my larger dataset, it is ordered by unique id, so they are grouped together in the dataframe, as is in this example, but I can't seem to get it to work. I am using R. Any suggestions?
